# CDK deploy creates and deletes immediately the stacks

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I am experiencing a strange behaviour with CDK.

I have a parent stack defined here:

```
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { CdkTsWorkshopStack } from "../lib/cdk-ts-workshop-stack";

function main() {
  const app = new cdk.App();
  const env_type = app.node.tryGetContext("env");
  const env_context = app.node.tryGetContext(env_type);
  const suffix = env_context["suffix"];
  const region = env_context["region"];
  const account = env_context["account"];
  const stackName = `${suffix}-testStack`;

  const stackProps = {
    env: { account: account, region: region },
    stackName: stackName,
  };

  const context = {
    env: env_type,
    suffix: suffix,
    region: region,
    account: account,
  };
  console.log(stackProps)
  console.log(process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT)
  console.log(process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION)
  new CdkTsWorkshopStack(app, "CdkTsWorkshopStack", stackProps, context);
  app.synth();
}

main();
```

and in another files i define these:

```
import { aws_dynamodb, RemovalPolicy, Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { CDKContext } from "../types";
import { StatelessStack } from "./stateless-stack";
import { StatefullStack } from "./storage-stack";

export class CdkTsWorkshopStack extends Stack {
  constructor(
    scope: Construct,
    id: string,
    props?: StackProps,
    context?: CDKContext,
  ) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new StatelessStack(this, "StatelessStack",props, context);
    new StatefullStack(this, "StatefullStack", props, context);
  }
}
```

While the Stateless and Statefull stacks are defined like:

```
import { aws_dynamodb, RemovalPolicy, Stack, StackProps, NestedStackProps, NestedStack } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { CDKContext } from "../types";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";

export class StatelessStack extends Stack {
  constructor(
    scope: Construct,
    id: string,
    props?: StackProps,
    context?: CDKContext,
  ) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const suffix = context?.suffix || "no-suffix";
    const env = context?.env || "dev";

    const hello = new lambda.Function(this, "HelloHandler", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda"),
      handler: "hello.handler",
      functionName: `${env}-hello-${suffix}`,
    });
  }
}
```

and

```
import { aws_dynamodb, RemovalPolicy, Stack, StackProps, NestedStackProps, NestedStack } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { CDKContext } from "../types";

export class StatefullStack extends Stack {
  constructor(
    scope: Construct,
    id: string,
    props?: StackProps,
    context?: CDKContext,
  ) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const suffix = context?.suffix || "no-suffix";
    const env = context?.env || "dev";

    const OrderTable = new aws_dynamodb.Table(this, "OrderTable", {
      tableName: `${env}-order-management-${suffix}`,
      partitionKey: {
        name: "orderId",
        type: aws_dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
      },
      billingMode: aws_dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      timeToLiveAttribute: "ttl",
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });
  }
}
```

So its not complex, the two stacks just create a lambda and a dynamodb table.
Then i wrap them under the parent stack and i am calling it from main file.

However, the thing that happens is that when i use for example
`cdk deploy -c env=prod --all`
the stacks are getting created and immediately i see from cloudformation console that update_complete_cleanup_in_progress and delete initiated.
All the stacks are getting deleted except for the parent (which contains only CDKMetadata)
The lambda and the table are gone.
What am i missing?

One thing more.
If i deploy specifically only one stack, lets say Stateless its fine. If i decide to deploy on a second run the Statefull, the Stateless gets deleted!!

Another interesting thing that happens, is if I remove the props and context values from the line where i instantiate the stateless and statefull stacks, these are getting env-agnostic and therefore they are deployed into the region/account they can identify from my profile (which is us-east-1) , while the parent stack gets deployed to eu-central-1 (env=prod). Then it works fine. The resources are there.
I am very confused of whats happening (especially with this env specific behaviour)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Although unrelated to the reported self-destruct behaviour, consider `CdkTsWorkshopStacks extends Construct` instead of `CdkTsWorkshopStack extends Stack`.  This eliminates the empty third stack that's currently being deployed.  See [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) for an example of defining multiple stacks in a Construct.

Answer (score 1):

When defining the props:

```
const stackProps = {
    env: { account: account, region: region },
    stackName: stackName,
  };
```

And passing it to all nested stacks:

```
new CdkTsWorkshopStack(app, "CdkTsWorkshopStack", stackProps, context);
...
new StatelessStack(this, "StatelessStack",props, context);
new StatefullStack(this, "StatefullStack", props, context);
```

you're explicitly naming all stacks the same.

Comment: Yes, nice catch! That was the problem. I wish cloudformation could be a bit verbose  so that I could see that